# convert a JSON file into a YAML file

Tags: java, json, yaml

I have to create a java code which can convert a JSON file into a YAML file and then compare it as both are correct or not

Can i get a code for this in any language as i am not allowed to use selenium, web driver or any tool

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Maybe try and see this: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml

Comment: *"any tool"* is quite all-encompassing... does it include third-party libraries? And if so, *why* aren't you allowed to use them?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303289/convert-a-json-file-into-a-yaml-file

Answer (score 4):

Is this a trick question?

From the [YAML 1.2 specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html):

> YAML can therefore be viewed as a natural superset of JSON, offering improved human readability and a more complete information model. This is also the case in practice; **every JSON file is also a valid YAML file**. This makes it easy to migrate from JSON to YAML if/when the additional features are required.

Any correct JSON file is by definition a correct YAML file - you do not have to convert or compare anything...